# VueJS update localStorage on Axios Response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

**A brief overview**
I'm basically building a simple weather widget where you input the city name and it'll fire off of an API request and get a weather object for that city.

The triggers for the form / API request are via `debounce` when someone stops typing and `onsubmit` when someone hits the enter key inside the input.

**The issue**
When someone searches for a city, I've got a `watch` function which sets the localStorage key `city` to equal whatever the user has inputted on the fly.

The problem is, if the city they've searched for doesn't exists then this will still be saved in the local storage and when the page reloads, it kills the widget because the API request fails to get details for that city.

I've tried applying the local storage value if the response status is 200 from the request, but the watcher just overwrites it.

So basically I need to set the `localStorage` value when the response is 200 and remove it if it's not.

I've tried doing an `if` statement for when the response is `200` and when it is not, but the value in Local Storage does not change.

Logically, I don't think the watcher is needed and the `city` value should not be updated until the response is 200 from the request.

Please take a look at my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/mattclarke/mjswgb63/

**Steps to replicate my issue**

1. Replace `London` with `Liverpool` to see the key updating in `Application -> LocalStorage`.
2. Change `Liverpool` to a non-existent city, for example `Londonpool`.
3. Refresh the page and you will see that the widget fails to display.
4. Change the `city` value in Local Storage back to `London` or any other city name.
5. Refresh the page and it should work again.

**Code**

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import _ from 'lodash'

const Toast = Swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: 'top-end',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 3000
})

export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
        return {
            weather: [],
            city: 'London',
            loading: false,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.weatherRequest();
    },
    watch: {
        city(city) {
            localStorage.city = city;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        weatherRequest: function() {
            this.loading = true;
            if(localStorage.city) {
                this.city = localStorage.city;
            }
            let cityName = this.city;
            if(cityName == "") {
                this.loading = false;
                return;
            }
            axios
            .get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&APPID=757cfb0ae831a41efa790e4fd9b008e8&units=metric')
            .then(response => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.weather = response.data;
                if(response.status == 200) {

                }
                Toast.fire({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: cityName + ' was loaded successfully.'
                });
            }, () => {
                this.loading = false;
                Toast.fire({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Couldn\'t find the city: ' + cityName,
                })
            })
        },
        getWeather: function() {
            this.weatherRequest()
        },
        debounceWeather: _.debounce(function() {
            this.weatherRequest()
        }, 700),
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="weatherRequest" class="mb-2 max-w-2xl mx-auto flex">
        <input type="text" v-model="city" class="border-2 p-2 w-full" @input="debounceWeather" placeholder="Please specify a city name" data-city-name>
    </form>
    <div class="max-w-2xl mx-auto">
        <div class="flex w-full rounded-lg" style="background: url('http://placeimg.com/640/480/nature');">
            <div class="text-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-lg text-sm w-full relative" style="background-color: rgba(42, 67, 101, 0.75); backdrop-filter: blur(5px);" data-weather-box>
                <div v-if="loading" class="absolute bg-blue-900 flex h-full items-center justify-center left-0 opacity-75 rounded-lg top-0 w-full"><img src="./assets/loading.svg" /></div>
                <div class="border-b-2 border-blue-800 mb-4 pb-4 flex justify-between">
                    <div class="text-left">
                        <div class="block text-lg">
                            <span data-city-result>{{ weather.name }}</span> (<span data-country>{{ weather.sys.country }}</span>)
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-blue-300" data-weather>{{ weather.weather[0].main }} - {{ weather.weather[0].description }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="absolute p-3 pr-5 right-0 text-5xl top-0 weather">
                        <i v-if="weather.weather[0].main == 'Clouds'" class="fas fa-cloud"></i>
                        <i v-if="weather.weather[0].main == 'Clear'" class="fas fa-sun text-yellow-400"></i>
                        <i v-if="weather.weather[0].main == 'Rain'" class="fas fa-cloud-rain"></i>
                        <i v-if="weather.weather[0].main == 'Snow'" class="far fa-snowflake"></i>
                        <i v-if="weather.weather[0].main == 'Mist'" class="fas fa-smog"></i>
                        <i v-if="weather.weather[0].main == 'Smoke'" class="fas fa-smog"></i>
                        <i v-if="weather.weather[0].main == 'Haze'" class="fas fa-smog"></i>
                        <i v-if="weather.weather[0].main == 'Thunderstorm'" class="fas fa-bolt"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Temp: </span><span class="text-white" data-temp>{{ weather.main.temp }}</span>&#176;c</div>
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Max: </span><span class="text-white" data-temp-max>{{ weather.main.temp_max }}</span>&#176;c</div>
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Min: </span><span class="text-white" data-temp-min>{{ weather.main.temp_min }}</span>&#176;c</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Pressure: </span><span data-pressure>{{ weather.main.pressure }}</span></div>
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Humidity: </span><span data-humidity>{{ weather.main.humidity }}</span></div>
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Visibility: </span><span data-visibility>{{ weather.visibility }}</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Wind Speed: </span><span data-wind-speed>{{ weather.wind.speed }}</span>mph</div>
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Wind Direction: </span><span data-wind-direction>{{ weather.wind.deg }}</span>&#176;deg</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Sunrise: </span><span data-sunrise>{{ new Date(weather.sys.sunrise * 1000).toLocaleString() }}</span></div>
                    <div><span class="text-blue-400 text-xs">Sunset: </span><span data-sunset>{{ new Date(weather.sys.sunset * 1000).toLocaleString() }}</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this working the way it should. I just had to remove the localStorage key if the response was not successful.

Correct code for the `weatherRequest` method below:

```js
weatherRequest: function() {
    this.loading = true;
    if(localStorage.city) {
        this.city = localStorage.city;
    }
    let cityName = this.city;
    if(cityName == "") {
        this.loading = false;
        return;
    }
    axios
    .get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&APPID=757cfb0ae831a41efa790e4fd9b008e8&units=metric')
    .then(response => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.weather = response.data;
        if(response.status == 200) {
            localStorage.city = cityName;
        }
        Toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: cityName + ' was loaded successfully.'
        });
    }, () => {
        this.loading = false;
        window.localStorage.removeItem('city');
        Toast.fire({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Couldn\'t find the city: ' + cityName,
        })
    })
},
```